# An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback

Tags: c++, winapi

Hello I am following along with the handmade hero game and I am getting this error: "Unhandled exception at 0x013B56B2 in win32_handmade.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback."

I am not sure what is causing this because I have the exact same code that he had and when I build in a .bat I get no errors.

Visual Studio is saying that the error is occurring at line 62 which is where the second internal void is at, but the error has been occurring no matter what is there.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define internal static 
#define local_persist static 
#define global_variable static

typedef int8_t int8;
typedef int16_t int16;
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef int64_t int64;

typedef uint8_t uint8;
typedef uint16_t uint16;
typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef uint64_t uint64;

// TODO(casey): This is a global for now.
global_variable bool Running;

global_variable BITMAPINFO BitmapInfo;
global_variable void *BitmapMemory;
global_variable int BitmapWidth;
global_variable int BitmapHeight;
global_variable int BytesPerPixel = 4;

internal void
RenderWeirdGradient(int BlueOffset, int GreenOffset)
{
int Width = BitmapWidth;
int Height = BitmapHeight;

int Pitch = Width * BytesPerPixel;
uint8 *Row = (uint8 *)BitmapMemory;
for (int Y = 0;
    Y < BitmapHeight;
    ++Y)
{
    uint32 *Pixel = (uint32 *)Row;
    for (int X = 0;
        X < BitmapWidth;
        ++X)
    {
        uint8 Blue = (X + BlueOffset);
        uint8 Green = (Y + GreenOffset);

        *Pixel++ = ((Green << 8) | Blue);
    }

    Row += Pitch;
}
 }

 internal void
 Win32ResizeDIBSection(int Width, int Height)
 {
// TODO(casey): Bulletproof this.
// Maybe don't free first, free after, then free first if that fails.

if (BitmapMemory)
{
    VirtualFree(BitmapMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
}

BitmapWidth = Width;
BitmapHeight = Height;

BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BitmapInfo.bmiHeader);
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = BitmapWidth;
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -BitmapHeight;
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

// NOTE(casey): Thank you to Chris Hecker of Spy Party fame
// for clarifying the deal with StretchDIBits and BitBlt!
// No more DC for us.
int BitmapMemorySize = (BitmapWidth*BitmapHeight)*BytesPerPixel;
BitmapMemory = VirtualAlloc(0, BitmapMemorySize, MEM_COMMIT, 
 PAGE_READWRITE);

// TODO(casey): Probably clear this to black
 }

 internal void
 Win32UpdateWindow(HDC DeviceContext, RECT *ClientRect, int X, int Y, int 
 Width, int Height)
 {
int WindowWidth = ClientRect->right - ClientRect->left;
int WindowHeight = ClientRect->bottom - ClientRect->top;
StretchDIBits(DeviceContext,
    /*
    X, Y, Width, Height,
    X, Y, Width, Height,
    */
    0, 0, BitmapWidth, BitmapHeight,
    0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight,
    BitmapMemory,
    &BitmapInfo,
    DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

}

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK
 Win32MainWindowCallback(HWND Window,
UINT Message,
WPARAM WParam,
LPARAM LParam)
{
LRESULT Result = 0;

switch (Message)
{
case WM_SIZE:
{
    RECT ClientRect;
    GetClientRect(Window, &ClientRect);
    int Width = ClientRect.right - ClientRect.left;
    int Height = ClientRect.bottom - ClientRect.top;
    Win32ResizeDIBSection(Width, Height);
} break;

case WM_CLOSE:
{
    // TODO(casey): Handle this with a message to the user?
    Running = false;
} break;

case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
{
    OutputDebugStringA("WM_ACTIVATEAPP\n");
} break;

case WM_DESTROY:
{
    // TODO(casey): Handle this as an error - recreate window?
    Running = false;
} break;

case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT Paint;
    HDC DeviceContext = BeginPaint(Window, &Paint);
    int X = Paint.rcPaint.left;
    int Y = Paint.rcPaint.top;
    int Width = Paint.rcPaint.right - Paint.rcPaint.left;
    int Height = Paint.rcPaint.bottom - Paint.rcPaint.top;

    RECT ClientRect;
    GetClientRect(Window, &ClientRect);

    Win32UpdateWindow(DeviceContext, &ClientRect, X, Y, Width, Height);
    EndPaint(Window, &Paint);
} break;

default:
{
    //            OutputDebugStringA("default\n");
    Result = DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam);
} break;
}

return(Result);
```

}

```
 int CALLBACK
 WinMain(HINSTANCE Instance,
HINSTANCE PrevInstance,
LPSTR CommandLine,
int ShowCode)
 {
 WNDCLASS WindowClass = {};

// TODO(casey): Check if HREDRAW/VREDRAW/OWNDC still matter
WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = Win32MainWindowCallback;
WindowClass.hInstance = Instance;
//    WindowClass.hIcon;
WindowClass.lpszClassName = "HandmadeHeroWindowClass";

if (RegisterClassA(&WindowClass))
{
    HWND Window =
        CreateWindowExA(
            0,
            WindowClass.lpszClassName,
            "Handmade Hero",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0,
            0,
            Instance,
            0);
    if (Window)
    {
        int XOffset = 0;
        int YOffset = 0;

        Running = true;
        while (Running)
        {
            MSG Message;
            while (PeekMessage(&Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if (Message.message == WM_QUIT)
                {
                    Running = false;
                }

                TranslateMessage(&Message);
                DispatchMessageA(&Message);
            }

            RenderWeirdGradient(XOffset, YOffset);

            HDC DeviceContext = GetDC(Window);
            RECT ClientRect;
            GetClientRect(Window, &ClientRect);
            int WindowWidth = ClientRect.right - ClientRect.left;
            int WindowHeight = ClientRect.bottom - ClientRect.top;
            Win32UpdateWindow(DeviceContext, &ClientRect, 0, 0, WindowWidth, 
 WindowHeight);
            ReleaseDC(Window, DeviceContext);

            ++XOffset;
            YOffset += 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO(casey): Logging
    }
}
else
{
    // TODO(casey): Logging
}

return(0);
 }
```

For who asked for the callstack here it is in better formating since it won't work well as a comment.

> win32_handmade.exe!Win32ResizeDIBSection(int Width, int Height) Line 62 C++
>       win32_handmade.exe!WIN32MainWindowCallback(HWND__ * Window, unsigned int Message, unsigned int WParam, long LParam) Line 118    C++
>       [External Code] 
>       win32_handmade.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * PrevInstance, char * CommandLine, int ShowCode) Line 184  C++
>       [External Code]

Comment: `#define global_variable static` is a lie. You are going to pay for that, sooner or later.

Comment: @IInspectable That's something that Casey does to differentiate the different uses of static - here's a good explanation of his reasoning for using this, and how you may remove them as the product matures:
https://hero.handmade.network/episode/code/day003/#1020
(In case you're curious)

Comment: @set I'm not curious, sorry. Casey was awesome, way back, when he did energetic talks. Today, he's just a biased, angry, bitter man, that will not hesitate to hold strong opinions even when those opinions are provably wrong, lead to inferior design, or otherwise questionable. One has to be very lucky to tune in on the right minute of the right day to find Casey communicating a valuable lesson.

Comment: @IInspectable Fair enough!